# Mating a morphism of pullbacks in $Cat$, when is this well-behaved?

Tags: ct.category-theory

In this cube of functors, the front and back faces are strict pullbacks

[image]

all the diagonal arrows are right adjoints: let's take the cube where the left adjoints have been considered, it is now filled by 2-cells obtained from said adjunctions:

[image]

What can be said about the top floor? In particular:

- (easy) when is the face filled by a 2-cell that makes for the obvious equality of 2-cells?
- (harder) when is the face filled by an isomorphism?

It feels like in a suitable 2-category of squares/pullback squares, these quadruples define adjunctions, so what I'm saying is that there is an adjunction between the $\begin{smallmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{smallmatrix}$ square and the $\begin{smallmatrix}X&Y\\Z&W\end{smallmatrix}$, and in particular an adjunction
$$ L:\begin{smallmatrix}X&Y\\Z&W\end{smallmatrix} \rightleftarrows \begin{smallmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{smallmatrix} :R$$
so I'm asking for a Beck-Chevalley type condition? Or some sort of exactness of another kind?

I am a bit confused. I don't really know where to look to find theorems about this situation.

Comment: OK, you mention Beck-Chevalley, but remember that where that arises (for quantifiers in categorical logic) it is over a pullback in the base category.  Do you have one of those somewhere in your situation?

Comment: Hmm, it is likely that I am using a looser meaning for "Beck-Chevalley", which I understand as a condition on a square of 1-cells in a 2-category, filled by a 2-cell. This is "BC" when mating appropriately (say, in case the vertical arrows have left adjoints) yields a pseudo-commutative square.